# How to upgrade Flyway to 4.0

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, flyway

I change version of the flyway gradle plugin from 3.2 to 4.0

```
plugins {
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "4.0"
}
```

And give a build error

```
Error:(10, 0) Plugin [id: 'org.flywaydb.flyway', version: '4.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Gradle Central Plugin Repository (plugin 'org.flywaydb.flyway' has no version '4.0' - see https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.flywaydb.flyway for available versions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradle plugin for flyway has not yet been published for version 4.0. For more information see this [issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1239) in the issue tracker.